# Custom Widget Development

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.9.3 version. I  tried to develop the custom widget for displayed the simple text content. I tried various development Tutorials to completes that processes. But end of that process created widget name doesn't shown on CMS->Widget->New Widget options. So please recommend so tutorial for this development.  And also there is any rules for "every widget related extensions are placed on app->code->Community file. Please give the suitable solution for this problem

Comment: Did you get your solution or did you looking for this still?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1). go to your extension etc folder
2). create widget.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
    <widget_instagrampro type="instagrampro/widgetblock">
        <name>Magecomp Instagrampro</name>
        <description type="desc">Magecomp Instagrampro</description>
    </widget_instagrampro>
</widgets>
```

put this code in that file and your widget will display when you create new widget

Answer (score 0):

You can check this module for create custom widget in magento 1.9.

https://github.com/dhrumin44/magento19_CustomWidgetType